# What will be the minimum iis version required to run asp.net 5 applications?

Tags: iis, asp.net

I'm considering using ASP.Net 5 for a new project, but I need to know what the minimum IIS version will be to host and run this application.

Comment: I have it running on IIS 8.5 on Windows 10 preview release but I assume that the minimum requirements will be Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ASP.Net 5 Home on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/home#minimum-requirements) you need at least Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.5.1 for hosting in IIS.

Windows 7 and Server 2008 [comes with IIS 7.5](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224609).

Also, refer to [.NET Framework System Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx)